# windows form that Calculate area and perimeter using C#

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a program that will Calculate area and perimeter of a square using C# I am using a forum app I am having a hard time starting the program I have the form made I just need help with the code part of it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would calculate the area of a square

```
using System;

namespace MyApp
{ 
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double dLength;
        double dArea;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of a side of Square :");
        dLength = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        dArea = dLength * dLength;
        Console.WriteLine("The area of Square is: " + dArea);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }     
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use console arguements, when it´s the following call in cmd.exe:

```
yourcompiled.exe length width
```

And you read it the given values with:

```
double length = double.Parse(args[0]);
double width = double.Parse(args[1]);
```

Be carefull in this case of the right call of arguements. Wrap an if around, if the

```
args.Length >= 2
```

If you wanna read read from Console, it´s simple to do it with C#:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

This command receive the user input till the user presses enter.

BUT THAT´S NOT A FORM! If you want to create a form in Visual Studio use "create new project" -> "Windows Form". And than all using prerequirements are given.

Edit: Or it´s also possible if it´s a form to create an symoblic link to it and then right click on the link -> properties and add after the double quotes on execution path the arguements in the way you would do on cmd.exe